# Is it possible to set a NSMutableDictionary key under a key?

Tags: objective-c, key, nsmutabledictionary

I set a `value` with a `key` like so:

```
[mutableDict setObject:@"Object to set" forKey:@"KeyOne"];
```

This works, but now I would like to add a `value` under `"Key one"`, like this:

```
[mutableDict setObject:@"Object a" forKey:@"KeyOne/detailsOnKey"];
```

Is this even possible? All help is appreciated

Comment: No, you can't set a key "under" a key in the way I think you're trying to do. I'm sure there's another way to accomplish what you want though. What is it that you're tying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a dictionary inside your dictionary, [dawg](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/xzibit-yo-dawg)

```
mutableDict[@"KeyOne"] = @{@"detailsOnKey": @"Object"}
```

Then you can access that nested dict like this:

```
mutableDict[@"KeyOne"][@"detailsOnKey"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple dictionaries for this.

```
//add a dictionary as the object for KeyOne
[mutableDict setObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] forKey:@"KeyOne"];

//add "Object a" under key one
[(NSMutableDictionary *)[mutableDict objectForKey:@"KeyOne"] setObject:@"Object a" forKey:@"detailsOnKey"];
```

//how to get the keyone/detailsonkey back ?, this way you can get it back

```
id objectA = [(NSMutableDictionary *)[mutableDict objectForKey:@"KeyOne"] objectForKey:@"detailsOnKey"];
```